# How can I look up all LAN domains?

Tags: networking, lan, raspberrypi

I have set up avahi on my raspberry pi but when I ping raspberrypi.local the domain doesn't get resolved.

I was wondering if there was a tool to look up all registered domains on LAN to look for my pi among them.

```
foo@blah-blah:~$ ping raspberrypi.local
ping: unknown host raspberrypi.local
```

Comment: you mean you look for something like `avahi-browse -rat` ?

Comment: @JoKeR that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ok then I'll convert it into answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avahi is a fully LGPL framework for Multicast DNS Service Discovery. As with `avahi-utils` if you'd like to discover/browse your local domains the simply run:

```
avahi-browse -rat
```

More detailed info on usage:

```
avahi-browse --help
```

Comment: Using `avahi-browse -rat` I found that chromecast uses mDNS as well! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can also use tools like `nmap` and `whois` if you're interested in discovering.

Comment: That doesn't seem to find _domains_, but _services_. I have on my network `morgen.local` and `traefik.local`, (as determined by `avahi-resolve -n`), but neither show in `avahi-browse`.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to setup local dns server for this.
More about installing and configuration you can find [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Second solution is to edit `/etc/hosts` and make records

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   xxx.yyyy.xx xxx

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

xxx.xxx.xx.x    raspberrypi.local
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  some_host.local
```

Only disadvantage of second solution is that you must edit `/etc/hosts` on all pc on lan.

Comment: I know about that, but avahi registers it so even when the IP changes or a new computer joins it can find it without any setup.

Comment: For name resolution can be used only "some kind" of `dns service`. Linux do not have `netbios` names. Linux do not distribute `hostname` on network and because of that you must make record.

Comment: This wasn't even true in 2015. Linux hosts _can_ have netbios names, and your average consumer router would register the machine names. The shortcoming is that you often want different names for the same machine, and consumer routers don't generally do that for you without a lot of work. Hence, Avahi.